# Angular component template does not update with events received by firebase onAuthStateChanged

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I can successfully pull the datas I want ,When I print them on the "html" page, datas don't show up at first.But datas show up when I change the page and come back.What is the problem, how can I solve it.

This is my notification.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "@firebase/auth"; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-notifications',
  templateUrl: './notifications.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notifications.page.scss'],
})
export class NotificationsPage implements OnInit {
  notifications : Array<any>=[]
  constructor(private db : AngularFireDatabase) { }

 ngOnInit() {
    
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=> {
      
      if(user){
        this.db.database.ref("/users/"+user.uid+"/notifications/").on("value",snap=>{this.notifications=[],snap.forEach(a=>{
         var type = a.child("type").val()
         var userpath = this.db.database.ref("/users/"+a.child("who").val())
         if(type=="request"){
           userpath.on("value",x=>{this.notifications.push({type:type,name:x.child("name").val(),pp:x.child("pp").val()})})
           
         } 
        })})
      }
    })
    }}
```

notifications.html :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  <ion-buttons slot="primary">
    
  <ion-button ><ion-icon size="large" name="paw-outline"></ion-icon></ion-button>
      
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
 <ion-list>
   <div *ngFor="let item of notifications">
   <ion-item *ngIf="item.type=='request'">
     <ion-label>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
   </ion-item>
  </div>
 </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple problems here:

**1) You don't unsubscribe the observable, when the component is destroyed.**

When you navigate and back and forth to your component, you will therefore have multiple subscriptions. You should be able to verify this in your developer console, e.g. by debugging or logging.
The function returns an unsubscribe function, see the firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged). You can use `ngOnDestroy` for an Angular component to unsubscribe from subscriptions.

```
onAuthStateChanged ( nextOrObserver :  Observer < any > | ( ( a :  User | null ) => any ) ,  error ? :  ( a :  Error ) => any ,  completed ? :  firebase.Unsubscribe ) : firebase.Unsubscribe
```

**2. You are subscribing in your component on `ngOnInit` which might be too late**

I suspect that when you subscribe, the user event was already fired. So you won't receive a value. It would be better to put the subscription into a (root) service so that you don't miss the user value and can cache it if needed.

E.g.

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthService {
   onAuthStateChanged() {
     return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(shareReplay(1));
   }
}
```

**3. Pushing values into an array does not trigger Angular change detection**

This will not trigger the Angular change detection:

```
this.notifications.push(value);
```

However this will:

```
this.notifications = [...this.notifications, value];
```

The reason for this is that in the case of `push` the array object reference does not change, so Angular will not trigger a change in the template. In the working example using a new array assignment, Angular will detect the change and update the template.

**Edit: To answer your question about the unsubscribe, here a concrete example:**

Oh, the snippet I posted shows the typing of the function.
You must do it like this:

```
this.unsubscribeFirebase = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=> {...});
```

Your component must implement OnDestroy, in your ngOnDestroy method you can then call the unsubscribe function:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  unsubscribeFirebase();
}
```

Comment: 'onAuthStateChanged() {
    return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(shareReplay(1));
  } ' i tried this but there is a error <https://prnt.sc/v3v961> I also could not understand how to implement 'ngondestroy' like this ? <https://prnt.sc/v3vbl4>

Comment: Oh, the snippet I posted shows the typing of the function.
You must do it like this:

` this.unsubscribeFirebase = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=> {...});`

Your component must implement OnDestroy, in your ngOnDestroy method you can then call the unsubscribe function:

`
ngOnDestroy() {
  unsubscribeFirebase();
}
`

Comment: I added the explanation to the answer so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

your data come after your html load,
you can use *ngif to solve your problem.

example: <ion-content *ngIf="notifications">